# XSLT loop returning the same value

Tags: xml, xslt

New to XSLT and i want to flatten out my XML file for (later) ingestion into SQL. Currently I'm having trouble looping through the XML document.  At the moment it picks up the number of tags but will return the same value. Also when there are loops within loops there seems to be a problem of not picking up a value at all.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Example>
  <Num>12</Num>
  <Num>13</Num>
  <Num>14</Num>
  <Num>15</Num>
  <Num>16</Num>
  <New>N</New>
  <Age>118</Age>
  <Name>
    <PrimNam>
      <Surnm>SAM</Surnm>
      <FstNm>SAM</FstNm>
      <SecNm>SAM</SecNm>
    </PrimNam>
    <Alias>
      <Id>12</Id>
      <DOB>01/01/1900</DOB>
      <AliasNam>
        <Surnm>SAM</Surnm>
        <FstNm>SAMUEL</FstNm>
      </AliasNam>
      <AliasDate>28/12/2018</AliasDate>
    </Alias>
  </Name>
</Example>
```

Here is what my XSLT looks like at the moment

```
<xsl:for-each select="Example/Num">
    <Num><xsl:value-of select="../Num"/></Num>
</xsl:for-each>

    <New><xsl:value-of select="Example/New"/></New>
    <Age><xsl:value-of select="Example/Age"/></Age>

    <xsl:for-each select="Example/Name/PrimNam">
        <Surnm><xsl:value-of select="../../Surnm"/></Surnm>
        <FstNm><xsl:value-of select="../../FstNm"/></FstNm>
        <SecNm><xsl:value-of select="../../SecNm"/></SecNm>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="Example/Name/Alias">
        <Id><xsl:value-of select="../../Id"/></Id>
        <DOB><xsl:value-of select="../../DOB"/></DOB>
            <xsl:for-each select="Example/Name/Alias/AliasNam">
                <Surnm><xsl:value-of select="../../../Surnm"/></Surnm>
                <FstNm><xsl:value-of select="../../../FstNm"/></FstNm>
            </xsl:for-each>
        <AliasDate><xsl:value-of select="../../AliasDate"/></AliasDate>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

And the resulting output looks like this

```
<Num>12</Num>
<Num>12</Num>
<Num>12</Num>
<Num>12</Num>
<Num>12</Num>
<New>N</NewCon>
<Age>118</Age>
<Surnm></Surnm>
<FstNm></FstNm>
<SecNm></SecNm>
<Id></Id>
<DOB></DOB>
<AliasDate></AliasDate>
```

Comment: What would your desired outcome XML look like? Please add that information with an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="Example/Num">
   ```

   puts you in the context of `Num`. In order to get the value of the
   current `Num`, you need to do:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   ```

   What you do:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="../Num"/>
   ```

   selects the **first** `Num` child of the **parent** of the current
   node - which is the same one for every `Num`.

---

2. The instruction:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="Example/Name/PrimNam">
   ```

   puts you in the context of `PrimNam`. In order to get the value
   `Surnm` from here, you must do:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="Surnm"/>
   ```

   not:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="../../Surnm"/>
   ```

   because `Surnm` is a **child** of `PrimNam`. The same applies to the
   other nodes you're unable to select.

---

Note that you could shorten your stylesheet considerably by using `xsl:copy` - for example:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Example/New"/>
```

instead of:

```
<New><xsl:value-of select="Example/New"/></New>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to flatten your XML.
One possibility is the following XSLT-1.0 template:

```
<xsl:template match="Example/Num | Example/New | Example/Age | Example/Name/PrimNam/* | Example/Name/Alias/Id | Example/Name/Alias/DOB | Example/Name/Alias/AliasNam/* | Example/Name/Alias/AliasDate">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The output is:

```
<Num>12</Num>
<Num>13</Num>
<Num>14</Num>
<Num>15</Num>
<Num>16</Num>
<New>N</New>
<Age>118</Age>
<Surnm>SAM1</Surnm>
<FstNm>SAM2</FstNm>
<SecNm>SAM3</SecNm>
<Id>12</Id>
<DOB>01/01/1900</DOB>
<Surnm>SAM</Surnm>
<FstNm>SAMUEL</FstNm>
<AliasDate>28/12/2018</AliasDate>
```

This is a flattened version of your input XML.